# Width doesn't change when setting height for an SVG in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

Is there a way to set an SVG as the complete background of a View component in React Native?  Right now when trying to take a simple solid color SVG, it seems like the height is set, but the width is ignored, and instead, it's proportionally set.

Here is an example:

```js
const SvgComponent = ({height, width, style}) => {
  return (
    <Svg viewBox="0 0 375 313" height={height} width={width} style={style}>
      <Path fill="#09f" d="M0 160V64h375v249H0z" />
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

```js
const View = () =>  {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View style={{ height: 80, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
      <SvgComponent
        height={80}
        width={width}
        style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 16, bottom: 0 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `viewBox` attribute sets a specific aspect ratio for the SVG, so if you want to set both `width` and `height` that unrelated one to another, omit the `viewBox`.

Comment: Hmm... that didn't seem to work in my case. Removing the `viewBox` attribute just made the color SVG a little sliver.  The closest thing I've gotten was to add the `preserveAspoectRatio="none"` but that leaves the very top's background color still showing. Any other thoughts?